# Whatsapp - customer solution query

Tags: twilio

I wanted to know if it is possible to have one-to-one conversation with customer and agent but also other agents can see the conversation & even reply on behalf of original agent

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Twilio Conversations](https://www.twilio.com/blog/introducing-twilio-conversations). Twilio Conversations gives you programmatic control over participant management for each conversation, allowing users to be added or removed.

Rather than spend the time to build on each channel primitive and having to implement channel orchestration, groups management, and message archives, that functionality is built-in.

Think of conversations like an audio conferencing bridge, but for messaging.

[Using Twilio Conversations (Using Conversation You Tube Video - Signal 2019)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pkQ6dSvTlo)